# Is it possible to change the Toolbar/ActionBar color within each page?

Tags: android

I have multiple pages. You cans swipe between them. My first page is all pink and my toolbar is pink so it can match with the page background. However, when I swipe to the next page, it's green. But the toolbar stays pink. Is there anyway the toolbar can change color depending on which page is present?